# Moving app to production mode in Symfony 2

Tags: deployment, symfony, production-environment

Can someone help me to move my Symfony 2 application into production mode?

Currently, the application is running properly in `/app_dev.php`.

I'm googling, but I'm not finding a definite guide for deployment in Symfony 2.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Couple more things to consider:

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
php app/console assets:install web_directory
php app/console assetic:dump web_directory
```

You might also run into permission issues with the cache directory.  I would actually first make sure everything works in development mode on the server before switching to production mode.  And if all you get is blank screens in production mode then set debug to true.  And of course know how to check your error logs.

Comment: The Symfony logs are in app/logs.  The web server depends on the server and how it is configured so can't really help there.

Comment: you answer was THE answer, thanks, by the way, all those who'll use this answer, everytime u change something in your  scripts,  do this, php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug, also sometime u need to change permission, so do a chown !!

Comment: This answer isn't standalone. Can you include the relevant bits of the other answer rather than start with "Couple more things"? E.g. "Configure rewrite rules to use `app.php`, not `app_dev.php`, remove `app_dev.php`"

Comment: Shouldn't you also run the `php app/console cache:warmup --env=prod` command?

Answer (score 11):

Moving Symfony2 to production means :

access the application through : app.php/

Test dev bundles won't be loaded since there is a condition into the AppKernel.php when you use app.php. If you want to unload bundle that should be used only in dev, you can place them into the this section (in appKernel.php)

```
if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sf2gen\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\Sf2genGeneratorBundle();
        }
```

You also need to make some server tuning by désactivating xdebug and adding eacclerator (or someting else for caching performance)

I also advice to rename app_dev.php to disactivate dev mode

Comment: can you be more explicit about how to setup the production mode

Answer (score 0):

Basic configuration information can be found here:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html

One important spot where many people stumble is asset management. When accessing the app via the app.dev front controller (see fist link), it may be necessary to dump the assets first. Read all about it here:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#cookbook-assetic-dumping

Answer (score 0):

The Symfony CookBook has now a few [recipes about deployment](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/deployment/index.html) covering:

- standard linux-based web-server: [How to Deploy a Symfony2 Application](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/deployment/tools.html),
- Microsoft Azure Website Cloud: [Deploying to Microsoft Azure Website Cloud](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/deployment/azure-website.html),
- Heroku Cloud: [Deploying to Heroku Cloud](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/deployment/heroku.html).

Answer (score 0):

Symfony2
How to Master and Create new Environments
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/environments.html