# vagrant and symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, vagrant

Hello I create my vagrant setup by [link](https://puphpet.com/#deploy-target). And server is up i can manage to go my example.com/web/app_dev.php/controller/... and its works all well when i comment in my app_dev.php

```
   // header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    //exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
```

but when i want to go site example.com/web/controller/.... its display blank 404 error what might be the problem ?
I do not use 127.0.0.1 insted of i use deflaut from setup 192.168.56.101

```
network:
    private_network: 192.168.56.101
    forwarded_port:
        9DcLNVHGAeca:
            host: '8889'
            guest: '22'
```

What can i do to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can either add your local IP to the array in the [`app_dev.php` line 14](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/web/app_dev.php#L14):

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
    || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
    || !(in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], 
        array('127.0.0.1', 'fe80::1', '::1', 'YOUR IP')) 
    || php_sapi_name() === 'cli-server')
)
```

or just uncomment the statements as you did in your question. It should be noted that the `app_dev.php` should not be reachable on your production server anyways because it reveals sensitive information about your setup.

Comment: ok but why I have 404 when link 'web/example/' and 'web/app_dev.php/example/' working well ?

Comment: Accessing `web/example` will access the production environment. Make sure to deploy your production mode correctly as [described here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9262632/1847340).